# ionic ANDROID_SDK_ROOT is undefined alguien sabe porque no compila

Tags: android, android-studio, ionic, cordova

Estoy intentando compilar mi aplicación de **ionic** para **android** pero el compilador me saca el siguiente error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya tengo instalado android studio. Inclusive cuando compilo desde la misma aplicación de android studio si sale el apk.

Esta es la versión del jdk de java.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Versión de android studio

Android Studio 3.5.1
Build #AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203, built on September 25, 2019

JRE: 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03 amd64

JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o

Windows 10 10.0

Realmente no se porque no compila.